# Amazon MWS, feed submission IDs returned are not unique

Tags: amazon-mws

Trying to integrate Amazon MWS into our software.

It would appear that the FeedSubmissionId(s) returned by SubmitFeed() are, at times, not unique. I found out the hard way, as the database returned an error since I have FeedSubmissionId as a Primary Key.

The issue went away since, after a few failed attempts, some time passed and SubmitFeed() finally returned a not-previously-used ID.

Can anyone confirm what I am seeing? FeedSubmissionId(s) not being unique? Is Amazon 'reusing' them? Are we supposed to use them and immediately discard them under the theory that could be 'reused'?

Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: I guess I don't understand how you are using it.  You submit a feed and then store that id so you can later query to get a feed processing status?   You should never use that id as the primary key to your table.  You can't guarantee uniqueness as you've found.

Comment: Hi ScottG, thanks for replying. Indeed, the intended use is the one you described. The documentation *does* say that the ID is unique. Anyhow, I have a slew of verified cases in which the same id is returned for a new feed e.g. 12h later and, if queried using GetFeedSubmissionList(), you can see that the SubmittedDate still refers to the first submitted feed. I am just trying to figure out how to handle this whole thing. Right now I'm just disregarding them and retrying SubmitFeed() multiple times till I get a new ID. Thanks for your input.

Comment: what is the purpose for calling submitfeed multiple times?  I submit a feed and then in a loop, I check every xx seconds to see if it was successful or not.  If not successful, I have I data problem, more than likely, so I use my notify process to alert me(the admin) that something is wrong.   I really could care less about the feed submission id.  I just use that to query the status of the submit request.  Once the request is submitted successfully, I'll log it, just so I can have an audit trail (my log has it's own PK ID, it's not feedsubmittionid), but then I don't care about it any more.

Comment: At first I wasn't sure if the ID was being "reused" or not. Meaning that if I got the same ID for a new feed I was left wondering if it "pointed" to the new feed or the old one. I was calling SubmitFeed() multiple times, i.e. trying to resubmit the new feed, to get an "unambiguous" id. Clearly, I will now adopt my own PK but that won't solve the main issue: the ID pointing to the "old" feed. I can't call GetFeedSubmissionList() or GetFeedSubmissionResult(). I need to disregard the ID, resubmit the feed till I get a brand new ID. MWS Support has been "investigating" this for over a month.